# How to rename the existing namespace with new namespace in wso2esb

Tags: xpath, wso2, xquery, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1,
I wish to change my request and response before sending to endpoint and client

so my request is

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh" xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
          <pr:authentication soapenv:her="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/her/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://webservices.temp.com/ProxyService">
             <pr:user>sec5</pr:user>
             <pr:password>ss</pr:password>
          </pr:authentication>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <open:clientRequest xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <env:EaiEnvelope xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh">
                <env:Language>en</env:Language>
                <env:UserId>admc</env:UserId>
                <env:Payload>
                   <ss:security xmlns:ss="http://eai.admc.kyt/security">
                      <ss:Request>
                         <ss:Operation_Name>securityrem</ss:Operation_Name>
                         <ss:customerID>
                            <ss:no>9875452</ss:no>
                            <ss:Service_Type>gsm</ss:Service_Type>
                         </ss:customerID>
                         <ss:customer>
                            <ss:isCredit>false</ss:isCredit>
                            <ss:Amount>100000</ss:Amount>
                            <ss:transaction_Id>4301298</ss:transaction_Id>
                            <ss:TransactionTypeID>228</ss:TransactionTypeID>
                            <!--<ss:DeductionPriorityCode>2</ss:DeductionPriorityCode>-->
                         </ss:customer>
                      </ss:Request>
                   </ss:security>
                </env:Payload>
             </env:EaiEnvelope>
          </open:clientRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I wish to change the **ss:security**  element namespace with **xmlns:emp="http://uri.open.gen/com"**  so my request should be change as per new Namespace its lke this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh" xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
      <pr:authentication soapenv:her="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/her/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://webservices.temp.com/ProxyService">
         <pr:user>sec5</pr:user>
         <pr:paempword>emp</pr:paempword>
      </pr:authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <open:clientRequest xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <env:EaiEnvelope xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh">
            <env:Language>en</env:Language>
            <env:UserId>admc</env:UserId>
            <env:Payload>
               <emp:safety xmlns:emp="http://uri.open.gen/com">
                  <emp:Request>
                     <emp:Operation_Name>securityrem</emp:Operation_Name>
                     <emp:customerID>
                        <emp:no>9875452</emp:no>
                        <emp:Service_Type>gsm</emp:Service_Type>
                     </emp:customerID>
                     <emp:customer>
                        <emp:isCredit>false</emp:isCredit>
                        <emp:Amount>100000</emp:Amount>
                        <emp:transaction_Id>4301298</emp:transaction_Id>
                        <emp:TransactionTypeID>228</emp:TransactionTypeID>
                        <!--<emp:DeductionPriorityCode>2</emp:DeductionPriorityCode>-->
                     </emp:customer>
                  </emp:Request>
               </emp:safety>
            </env:Payload>
         </env:EaiEnvelope>
      </open:clientRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So i have tried with xquery but its unable to do someone please responed for this
i have tried with this xquery

```
<x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope";
declare namespace soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace open="http://www.ffff.org/";
declare variable $emp as xs:string+:="http://uri.open.gen/com";
declare namespace env="http://eai.jj.mmm/Envelope";
declare variable $Request xs:string+ external;
declare variable $EaiEnvelope as document-node() external;
element{'open:clientRequest'}{
element{'*:EaiEnvelope'}{$EaiEnvelope//*:EaiEnvelope/*[not(local-name()='Payload')],
element{'*:Payload'}{
element{QName($emp,concat('emp',':','safety'))}
$Request//env:Payload/*[1]/*
    }}
    }
</x>
```

but its giving exception token is not specified
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If XSLT 2.0 is an option for you (for example using saxon XSLT processor). You can apply this stylesheet to youe input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ss="http://eai.admc.kyt/security"
    xmlns:emp="http://uri.open.gen/com"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ss:*">
        <xsl:element name="emp:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>            
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@ss:*">
        <xsl:attribute name="emp:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>            
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Every attribute and element in `http://eai.admc.kyt/security` namespace in input will be in the other namespace in the output.

**One note**: it won't change in the comments

Comment: neither your input nor my xslt contains a reference to a cs3 prefix... seems weird. I see you are using Xalan xslt processor, can you try with saxon?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XQuery option...

**XML Input**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh" xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
        <pr:authentication soapenv:her="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/her/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:pr="http://webservices.temp.com/ProxyService">
            <pr:user>sec5</pr:user>
            <pr:password>ss</pr:password>
        </pr:authentication>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:clientRequest xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <env:EaiEnvelope xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh">
                <env:Language>en</env:Language>
                <env:UserId>admc</env:UserId>
                <env:Payload>
                    <ss:security xmlns:ss="http://eai.admc.kyt/security">
                        <ss:Request>
                            <ss:Operation_Name>securityrem</ss:Operation_Name>
                            <ss:customerID>
                                <ss:no>9875452</ss:no>
                                <ss:Service_Type>gsm</ss:Service_Type>
                            </ss:customerID>
                            <ss:customer>
                                <ss:isCredit>false</ss:isCredit>
                                <ss:Amount>100000</ss:Amount>
                                <ss:transaction_Id>4301298</ss:transaction_Id>
                                <ss:TransactionTypeID>228</ss:TransactionTypeID>
                                <!--<ss:DeductionPriorityCode>2</ss:DeductionPriorityCode>-->
                            </ss:customer>
                        </ss:Request>
                    </ss:security>
                </env:Payload>
            </env:EaiEnvelope>
        </open:clientRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XQuery**

```
declare namespace emp="http://uri.open.gen/com";
declare namespace pr="http://webservices.temp.com/ProxyService";
declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
declare namespace open="http://www.oly.org/";
declare namespace env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh";

declare function local:ident($node as node()) {
    if ($node instance of element()) then 
        if (namespace-uri($node) = 'http://eai.admc.kyt/security') then
            local:change-ss($node)
        else
            element {$node/name()} {$node/@*,
                for $child in $node/node() return local:ident($child)}
    else if ($node instance of attribute()) then
        if (namespace-uri($node) = 'http://eai.admc.kyt/security') then
            local:change-ss($node)
        else
            $node
    else if ($node instance of comment()) then
        local:change-ss($node)
    else 
        $node
};

declare function local:change-ss($node as node()) {
    if ($node instance of element()) then
        element {xs:QName(concat('emp:',$node/local-name()))} {
            for $node in $node/(@*|node())
            return
                local:ident($node)
        }
    else if ($node instance of attribute()) then
        attribute {xs:QName(concat('emp:',$node/local-name()))} {$node}
    else if ($node instance of comment()) then
        comment {replace($node,'(</?)ss:','$1emp:')}
    else
        $node
};

local:ident(/*)
```

**XML Output**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <pr:authentication xmlns:pr="http://webservices.temp.com/ProxyService"
                         soapenv:her="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/her/next"
                         soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
            <pr:user>sec5</pr:user>
            <pr:password>ss</pr:password>
        </pr:authentication>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <open:clientRequest xmlns:open="http://www.oly.org/">
            <env:EaiEnvelope xmlns:env="http://eai.ttt.pp.hh">
                <env:Language>en</env:Language>
                <env:UserId>admc</env:UserId>
                <env:Payload>
                    <emp:security xmlns:emp="http://uri.open.gen/com">
                        <emp:Request>
                            <emp:Operation_Name>securityrem</emp:Operation_Name>
                            <emp:customerID>
                                <emp:no>9875452</emp:no>
                                <emp:Service_Type>gsm</emp:Service_Type>
                            </emp:customerID>
                            <emp:customer>
                                <emp:isCredit>false</emp:isCredit>
                                <emp:Amount>100000</emp:Amount>
                                <emp:transaction_Id>4301298</emp:transaction_Id>
                                <emp:TransactionTypeID>228</emp:TransactionTypeID>
                                <!--<emp:DeductionPriorityCode>2</emp:DeductionPriorityCode>-->
                            </emp:customer>
                        </emp:Request>
                    </emp:security>
                </env:Payload>
            </env:EaiEnvelope>
        </open:clientRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The 2 XQuery functions can be combined to make it smaller, but I thought it was a little more readable.